# Where does DataRowCollection.Add method insert the new row?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out where DataRowCollection.Add(DataRow row) inserts the new row into its datatable.  Is it at the end of the table, like an append?  Is it random?

Also, I want to use this while I'm for looping through a datatable.  If some condition exists, add a new row containing different data to run through the For loop to the end of the datatable.  Are there any specific problems with this approach?  How else might I handle it?

EDIT: I am For Looping through a .Net DataTABLE stored in memory.  I'm not touching the dataBASE where the original data is stored during this looping operation.  The DataTABLE is populated prior to the loop and is not a problem.

Here is relavant code:

```
 DataTable machineANDlastDate = new DataTable();
//Populate machineANDlastDate  

for (int i = 0; i < machineANDlastDate.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   lastFutureDate = DateTime.Parse(machineANDlastDate.Rows[i]["MaxDueDate"].ToString());
   newDateTime = lastFutureDate.AddDays(frequency);    //This is where the new date is created.
   machineSerial = machineANDlastDate.Rows[i]["machineSerial"].ToString();

   if (newDateTime < DateTime.Now)
   {
          machineANDlastDate.Rows.Add(new String[] { machineSerial,         newDateTime.AddDays(frequency).ToString() });

          continue;
   } 
  ...Removed for irrelevancy...
}
```

Is this a valid way to add a row to the end of the datatable?

Comment: unless it's a hash, the add goes on the end

Comment: I think hashes are more common where you have key/values. The key is hashed so the value lookup is fast.

Comment: I don't see any relevance of Hashes to my situation.  I'm using strings in a DataTable, there are no hashes involved.

Comment: I think Alex just meant that `Add` adds the new item to the end in every collection except hashes. Your collection is not a hash, so you won't have that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is always added to the end of the collection.

If you `for` loop through the database, there shouldn't be a problem, if you begin at the beginning of the data table and finish at the end of it or smth similar. However, you will then also loop through the newly created data rows, and I don't know whether you want to achieve this. You only could get problems if you take a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop instead because it cannot handle modifications of the underlying collection.

Comment: Yes, I do want to loop through the new items, thats the point.  If a certain condition exists, I modify that data then I want to run the modified version through the loop.  I'm aware of the foreach loop problem with the underlying connection, so your saying the For loop doesn't have this problem?

Comment: If you don't remove any items, I cannot imagine any problem if the condition is still valid beforehand. The important difference between the two loops `for` and `foreach` lays in the indexing of the `for` loop. Because you work with indices there, you avoid the problem you would have with the `foreach` loop. Hope that helps.

Comment: What about using the DataTable's Rows.Count method as a limit?  Will that update with each loop iteration?

Comment: that should certainly do the job. If you add a row to the rows collection, the `Rows.Count` property is also incremented, which means that in the next step, the condition can be true again. `i` is incremented at the end of the loop where `Rows.Count` should already be incremented, if the condition was met. Your code above seems like it should work now, is there another problem with it?

Comment: No, I was just unsure where the insert occurred and wanted to make sure i was avoiding the foreach underlying collection issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a row is new or not you can check the `DataRow.RowState` property.

```
// your code to add rows
...

// process added rows
foreach (DataRow row in machineANDlastDate.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

// now confirm new rows (they won't have a RowState of Added after this)
machineANDlastDate.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this AcceptChanges() method, but I'm not concerned with where/when the row comes from, I just want to process it when the loop gets to it.

Comment: AcceptChanges changes the RowState on all rows to Unmodified. When you add rows they start with a RowState of Added - you can use this to process only new rows. You only need to call AcceptChanges when you're finished if you might have to reprocess and don't want to process the same rows again.

Answer (score 0):

It's always at the end of the table, as far as i know most of the DataBase conectors, whe you use their add row, its always at the end.

Answer (score -3):

The `Add` method will insert a `DataRow` into a `DataRowCollection` object only. To actually add the `DataRow` to the data table, you will need to call the `NewRow` method which appends itself onto the `DataTable`, and thus appends the row to the table in that database. For reference, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yfsd47w.aspx

Comment: No, it is exactly the other way around. You first have to create a new row with the `NewRow` method and afterwards, you need to add it to the data table with the `Add` method. The DataTable is kind of represented by the DataRowCollection.

Comment: A DataTable contains a DataRowCollection (a DataTable HAS a DataRowCollection).  There are not related or linked, the DataTable is a composition of many other objects, including a DataRowCollection.

Comment: The NewRow method will return you a row instance that has the same column structure as the table. This allows you to reference cells by column using the indexer. You still need to Add the row to the table once it's populated with data.